# If statement in viewModelScope

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

Why function return always false? And how to fix this?

```
fun testFun(id: Int): Boolean {
    var isExists = false
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val itemFromDb = database.getDetails(id)
        if (itemFromDb != null) // never executing
            isExists = true
    }
    return isExists // always return false
}
```

Comment: when you launch a coroutine, it shift to kind of another thread and the return gets executed of that current thread and it does not wait for the results

Comment: @Abdul, you should write it as an answer (and change the code).

Comment: Are you sure `if (itemFromDb != null)` has never called?

Comment: @CoolMind, yes i sure. And database.getDetails(id) is suspended function also (Room).

Comment: Maybe any errors appeared? I often use try-catch.

Comment: No errors. Database return valid object.

Comment: Well, if `itemFromDb` has been gotten, why can't the next line execute? Does debug interrupt? You can set breakpoints at `if (itemFromDb != null)` and `return isExists` to understand what stops first.

Comment: Debug not interrupt. The following code runs as it should.

Comment: Do you mean that `testFun` finishes before `if (itemFromDb != null)` and so that line never executes?

Comment: Function executing `val itemFromDb = database.getDetails(id)` and skip next 2 lines

Comment: This is strange. Maybe you can rebuild the project. Also you can raise exceptions inside the coroutine in different places to check if it reaches that code. Also maybe Kotlin optimises the code too hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution suits me.

```
suspend fun testFun(id: Int): Boolean {
    var isExists = false
    val result = viewModelScope.await {
        val itemFromDb = database.getDetails(id)
        if (itemFromDb != null)
            isExists = true
        return@async isExists
    }
    result.await()
    return isExists
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Abdul said, your coroutine switches to another thread and continues there. But a `testFun` method doesn't stop working and finishes before the coroutine finish.

You can rewrite your code. For instance, make `testFun` a suspended function and write everything inside in one block. Or synchronize the method and the coroutine. I usually do this with `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`, didn't work with `viewModelScope.launch` either.

Maybe wrong solutions:

```
fun suspend something(): Boolean {
    var result = false

    result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        ...
        true
    }
    ... // Other code in the main thread.

    return result
}

fun something(): Boolean {
    var result = false
    val job = launch() {
        result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            ...
            true
        }
        ... // Other code in the main thread.
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So this is also a possible solution. I have tried it here and working fine

```
 fun something(): Boolean = runBlocking (Dispatchers.IO){
        return@runBlocking database.getDetails(id)!=null
    }
```